# Runnable JavaCV Project in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, opencv, executable-jar, javacv

I'm developing an simple application that capture images through webcam using the OpenCV wrapper, JavaCV.

I tried to run the basic source code for JavaCV in Netbeans IDE 7.0.1 in Windows 7 OS, it works but when I run the executable .jar file or compiled/build file in both Windows 7 and Mac OS , the web camera feed is not working or showing. Can you please give me step by step process in solving this? I'm only an amateur java programmer so easy to understand instructions/answers will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Saying it doesn't work doesn't help us at all. Help us to help you and state the errors you are having.

Comment: Here is the source code of the simple application for capturing image through webcam http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/javacv-capture-image-from-webcam.html

When I run this source code as a project in NetBeans, there is no exceptions but when I build the project to a .jar file and run it both in windows 7 and mac os there is no exceptions also but the camera feed is not showing in the canvas frame while when I run in on netbeans there is a camera feed. Is there a solution in this problem? Or what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

To get a standalone JAR that works across platforms we need to bundle the native libraries of OpenCV as well, in a similar fashion to [the FaceApplet sample](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/HowToMakeAnApplet).